# Mutiple Resultset in EF Core 1.0

Tags: entity-framework-core

Does Entity Framework Core 1.0 Support multiple result set?
If so can you give please give an example based on the below stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetProductInfo
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT ID,PRODUCT_NAME FROM PRODUCT
     SELECT ID,CATEGORY_NAME FROM PRODUCT_CATEGORY   
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of support are you looking for? You can certainly drop-down to ADO.NET.

```cs
var command = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "uspGetProductInfo";

db.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // TODO: Read products
        }

        reader.NextResult();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // TODO: Read product categories
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    db.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```